# How to use for loop inside foreach using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, for-loop, foreach, sublist

I'm using flutter for connecting mobile application with another devices via bluetooth. I have a file contains hexadecimal values so I convert the content of the file to list and the I splitted this list into sublists and every list contains 19 values.
At first I have to send the first paquet (first sublist) and then if I recieve a notification I have to send the rest one by one and after sending every paquet I have to recieve a success notification.
for now, I send the first one and I recieved the notification but the rest of the paquets wasn't sent except when I click another time on the button.
this is my code :

```
 await Future.forEach(chunks, (chunk) async {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                          c.write(chunk as List<int>, withoutResponse: true);
                          c.read();
                        }
                        if (c.isNotifying == true) {
                          for (int i = 1; i < 247; i++) {
                            c.write(chunk as List<int>, withoutResponse: true);
                            c.read();
                            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
                          }
                        }
                      });
                    },
```

Please tell me if there's some wrong in  my code and thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

i have some questions.

1. Why you hold the commands in a File? `List<List<Command>>` is no option for you?
2. You can use write with response to get response to send further commands

PS: Please use forEach without functions literals like this

**BAD:**

```
Future.forEach((chunks) {...});
```

**GOOD:**

```
for (var chunk in chunks) {...}
```